# Updating an SQL table from another using certain parameters and only updating certain parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am currently working with a couple of databases using SQL Server 2008. Just recently I have noticed that one of my tables in my database has incorrect data and so to rectify this (as I have a copy of the table with the correct data in the same database) I thought to use an update to update the data from one table to another.

So for explanation purposes, Table X, has the incorrect data. Table Y, has the correct data.

The incorrect data which is making my job more difficult is the only unique identifier to each record and I am only wanting to update these unique identifiers between two specific dates.

What I have got so far is:

```
UPDATE X
SET    X.number = Y.number
FROM   X, Y
WHERE  X.Date >= '20130107' AND X.Date <= '20140630'
AND    Y.Date >= '20130107' AND Y.Date <= '20140630'
```

Unfortunately whilst this does the job, it takes the unique identifier for the top row of Y and updates it to all rows in X. Obviously this is not what I am looking for as I need Y.record1 to match with X.record1, Y.record2 to match with X.record2 etc.

Any help would be most appreciated, and feel free to ask questions should I have confused you.

Thank you.

Comment: Im confused. isnt x.number already equal to y.number? what field tells you its the same? and if y table contains the correct table why not just delete rows in x with these dates then insert y with these dates?

Comment: You either need a key or even multiple fields that could be used to identify each unique row.

Comment: X.number is not equal to y.number. That is the issue I am trying to fix. A part from that the fields are exactly the same. The reasoning for not deleting the data and then inserting it once more is mainly for the fact of I don't like deleting data, as it tends to lead to problems (i.e. missing data, duplicate data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could technically make this work by using a

```
row_number() over (order by xyz)
```

on both filtered sets to create temporary keys to use in the update. If you augment that with CTEs it will be a little easier.

BUT(!) this is a relatively complex way of solving the issue you describe. With the data you have given it seems a lot easier to delete the bad data and reinsert from the table that is still good.

Comment: I'm pretty new to SQL and I read about using this row_number() function, but it did confuse me a little. It seems everyone is suggesting to delete the data and then insert. I'm not a fan of this method, but seeing as everyone is suggesting that's the best methodology I guess I'll go for it. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score -1):

I may have misunderstood your question but as long as the rows in table Y are an exact copy the rows you would like in table X I would delete the rows from table X using your date criteria above.

```
DELETE FROM X WHERE X.Date >= '20130107' and X.Date <= '20140630'
```

Then simply insert the rows from Y again with the date criteria used on the selection.

```
INSERT INTO X SELECT Y.* FROM Y WHERE Y.Date >= '20130107' and Y.Date <= '20140630'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: As everyone is suggesting the delete and re-insert method, I will probably take this approach. Thanks for your help.